# Please explain this pattern/Message related issue and help with finding workaround

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, pattern-matching, message-coding, argument-patterns

I attempted to clean up my code and also add messages to functions if they are called with wrong arguments. This introduced some error which I tracked down to the following:

```
ClearAll[fun, rep, x, y];
General::argerr = "Something is wrong with arguments passed to the function. Either wrong number or no numerical values.";
fun[var1_?NumericQ, var2_?NumericQ] := Print["everything okay. Sum: ",var1 + var2];
fun[args__] := Message[fun::argerr];

rep = {x -> 2, y -> 3};
fun[x, y] /. rep
```

> ```
> fun::argerr: Something is wrong with arguments passed to the function. Either wrong number or no numerical values. *)
> ```

This is what I expected since both `x,y` are non-numerical when `fun` is called. What is surprising (to me): Just comment out the `fun[args__]` part and the evaluation of `fun[x,y]/.rep` yields the result `(* everything okay. Sum: 5 *)`. I'd still expect the function to be called with symbolic `x,y`, hence failing since non-numerical values which should (as I understood it) output something like `fun[x,y]/.{x->2,y->3}`.

So to me, two questions are arising:

- How come, that getting rid of the custom message makes the code output the sum of both arguments?
- What would be a way to keep the message and still be able to apply the `ReplaceAll` (unfortunately I need the replacement at some point)? This `fun[x/.rep,y/.rep]` works but I failed to implement this for arbitrary amount of arguments. I tried to play with `Map` but didn't succeed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1

After commenting the second definition, `fun[x,y]` was evaluated and left in this form since no definition was provided for symbolic arguments. Then the replacement was done and `tutorial/Evaluation` says:

> [...] in evaluating an expression like h[e1, e2, ...]. Every time the expression changes, the Wolfram Language effectively starts the evaluation sequence over again.

So it was evalauted again, this time the definition was found.

Ad 2

I suppose this is way you need:

```
fun @@ ({x, y} /. rep)
```

p.s. you can always use `Trace` to get initial guess about what was done. Like `fun[x, y] /. rep // Trace // Column` and `fun @@ ({x, y} /. rep) // Trace//Column`

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! Short while still being extremely informative and helpful.